# Accessing a dictionary within gmail

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

Is there a way to integrate a dictionary with gmail in google-chrome browser? Whenever I read or compose a mail, I wish to right-click on a word and find a 'synonyms' option similar to what I see in my MS word when I come across an unknown or uncommon word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not be a dictionary, they list definitions . That would be a thesaurus which would list synonyms. Depending on your browser there are various extensions you can get to do this.

If you use Google chrome, go to the chrome app store and type "thesaurus" in the search. The "Google Dictionary" extension  may also have this function as well.
IF you have Firefox, click add-ons and you can repeat the same process, however I don't believe there are as many options.